# Flask with Zoho - SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first

Tags: python, flask, smtp, zoho, flask-mail

In development environment I tested Flask mailer successfully connecting to personal Gmail account. I switched to Zoho with the same structure of config but it produces following error:

```
>>> send_password_reset_email(user)
>>> Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "app/email.py", line 8, in send_async_email
    mail.send(msg)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 492, in send
    message.send(connection)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 152, in __exit__
    self.host.quit()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 772, in quit
    res = self.docmd("quit")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 393, in docmd
    self.putcmd(cmd, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 341, in putcmd
    self.send(str)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 333, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

*config.py*

```
class Config(object):
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.zoho.com'
    MAIL_PORT = '587'
    MAIL_USE_TLS = '1'
    MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER = 'admin@mydomain.com'
    MAIL_USERNAME = 'admin@mydomain.com'
    MAIL_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
    ADMINS = 'admin@mydomain.com'
```

*routes.py*

```
@app.route('/recover', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_password_request():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('manage'))
    form = ResetPasswordRequestForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user:
            send_password_reset_email(user)
        flash('Check your email for the instructions to reset your password')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('recover.html', form=form)
```

*email.py*

```
def send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)

def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body):
    msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    msg.html = html_body
    Thread(target=send_async_email, args=(app, msg)).start()

   def send_password_reset_email(user):
        with app.app_context(), app.test_request_context(base_url='https://example.com'):
            token = user.get_reset_password_token()
            send_email('[MyDomain] Reset Your Password',
                   sender=app.config['ADMINS'][0],
                   recipients=[user.email],
                   text_body=render_template('email/reset_password.txt', user=user, token=token),
                   html_body=render_template('email/reset_password.html', user=user, token=token))
```

Zoho account seems to be configured well (no blacklisted IP's etc.). After my first attempt with this config I received an e-mail from Zoho support alerting me that a **new login** was made from a new IP address. However, the reset password email has never been sent.

I tried lots of tweking of config file but the issue might be somewhere else. Any help would be very appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

After wraping the quit function in try-except block, I finally came to a real error that causes the e-mail not to be sent. The complete traceback now looks like:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "app/custom_mailer.py", line 11, in send_async_email
    mail.send(msg)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 495, in send
    message.send(connection)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 430, in send
    connection.send(self)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 195, in send
    message.rcpt_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 750, in sendmail
    self.rset()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 469, in rset
    return self.docmd("rset")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 394, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 368, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Although this error appeared to be solved in some of closed questions here on Stackoverflow, I cannot make this piece of code work ..

Comment: Why the combined `app.app_context()` and `app.test_request_context()`? Are you calling that function from some non-request context elsewhere? You don't need that when calling this from a view, the context is already set up. Only set up the context in the code that uses `send_password_reset_email()` outside of a view. (No, this isn't the issue with your email sending).

Comment: Yes, for testing purposes I called that function from an interpreter outside of the app itself. Anyways, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Looking at this again, the error happens *at context exit*. Either the email successfully was sent already, and the remote connection closed early (and so sending `quit` fails) or there was an exception while sending *and* then the `quit` command also fails and the original exception is lost. You could put a `try...except smtplib.SMTPException: pass` around [line 152 of `home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py`](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-mail/blob/master/flask_mail.py#L152) (temporarily) to figure out which one of the two this is.

Comment: (I'd make a pull request with the project to handle that failure mode better, but the project has clearly been dead for 4 years now).

Comment: It worked. After wraping the quit command in try-except I receive following error:

`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 750, in sendmail
    self.rset()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 469, in rset
    return self.docmd("rset")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 394, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 368, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")`


I found some solved issues here with this error, but no solution seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no ideas there. Do add that traceback to your question for others with more experience with this to be able to help.